# foreach file in folder, rename and save

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I have a simple foreach here where I am have got the folder location using the `folderBrowserDialog` tool and am now trying to go through each one of the files and replace certain characters within the file name.

I am getting an error which says it cannot find the file when it gets to this part of the code `File.Move(_FileName, _NewFileName);`

Can anyone shed any light on this? Would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
foreach (FileInfo Files in Folder.GetFiles())
            {
                _FileName = Files.Name;

                _NewFileName = _FileName.Replace(" ", "-").Replace(",", "-");

                File.Move(_FileName, _NewFileName);

                File.Delete(_FileName);

            }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `Files.FullName` not `Files.Name`

[`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) includes the full path (i.e. `C:\test\foo.txt`) which is needed by `File.Move()` and `File.Delete()` while `Name` is just the file name itself (i.e. `foo.txt`).

**Edit:**

@crashmstr is correct you should not do a string replace on the full path. All in all I'd probably do it this way:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in Folder.GetFiles())
{
    string originalFileName = file.FullName;
    string fileName = file.Name.Replace(" ", "-").Replace(",", "-");
    string newFileName = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, fileName);

    File.Move(originalFileName, newFileName);
}
```

Also keep in mind `File.Delete()` is not needed here, since the original file won't be there anymore after you move it.

Comment: Though that could have problems if there are spaces in the folder name (for the replace)

Comment: Hello, thankyou for your quick response, I am still getting an error - "Could not find a part of the path." What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove an item from the collection which you are iterating.

You can store the list of files that you get from Folder.GetFiles() into some variable and iterate over it with foreach.

Comment: He's modifying the file system, not the collection - there's a difference

Comment: DirectoryInfo.GetFiles returns an array, and arrays cannot grow or shrink. In particular, GetFiles returns a new array containing the list of files in the moment you called GetFiles, so, the array doesn't changes over time.